# Azure DevOps App service deployment using Azure Artifacts doesn't work

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-artifacts

I am trying to deploy a .Net WebApp on Azure App Service using Azure DevOps.
Everything works fine when I build and deploy the generated .zip file using build and release pipelines.

But when I try to store the built artifact as a Package in Azure Artifacts and then try to deploy that package using Release, it is not working.

My Build pipeline

```
trigger:
- ubuntu-build

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: Build_Stage
    displayName: Build .NetCore App
    jobs:
      - job: webapp
        displayName: Build App
        variables:
          solution: '**/*.sln'
          buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
          buildConfiguration: 'Release'

        steps:
        - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'build'
            projects: '**/*.csproj'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'


        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishWebProjects: true
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            

        - script: ls $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          inputs:
            targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            artifact: 'WebApp'
            publishLocation: 'pipeline'
        
        
        

      - job: publish
        displayName: Publish artifact to Azure Artifacts
        dependsOn: webapp
        
        steps:

        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            buildType: 'current'
            downloadType: 'single'
            artifactName: 'WebApp'
            downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            cleanDestinationFolder: true

        - script: ls $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

        - task: UniversalPackages@0
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/webapp.zip'
            feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
            vstsFeedPublish: 'id'
            vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'webapp'
            versionOption: 'minor'
```

I can see the generated artifact in Azure Artifacts
[image]

I have added it as an Azure Artifact in the Release Pipeline

[image]

However, when I try to add it in the App Service Deploy task, I get this 'This artifact cannot be browsed.' at the top. This is unlike when I use a Build artifact where I can select the actual generated .zip file.

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong in build or in storing the generated .zip file in Azure Artifacts?

Comment: You shouldn't use "release" pipelines. Release pipelines and classic build pipelines are both deprecated in favor of YAML pipelines. There's no reason to use Azure Artifacts at all for any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'This artifact cannot be browsed.'

This message means that when you are configuring the pipeline, the pipeline doesn't know what files are in the artifact package.

As you mentioned in the comment, you can add the `/webapp.zip` and use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_webapp/webapp.zip` as input since you know this zip file is in the package. But when we configure the pipeline, the pipeline does not try to get the files in the package.

You can also view the Azure Artifact page. It also doesn't show on the page which files are included in the package. If you're using a package uploaded by another user, you won't know what's in it until you download it using the universal download command.

Comment: When I do this, it deploys the app to App Service but I get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." in the browser after deployment.
Is there a permissions issue with Azure Artifacts or something?

Comment: Never Mind, got it working after adding "/webapp.zip" at the end.
So the entire path is "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_webapp/webapp.zip"

I guess by just setting it to "_webapp" it was messing up the app service deployment.
Although, why can't we browse the artifact after adding it in the Release still remains my question. 
If I add the Build artifact, it can browse the folder and show the webapp.zip, so why can't with Azure Artifacts?

Comment: Oh, thank you for sharing this information to add "/webapp.zip" at the end.  Sorry for not double checking the deployment results.  I will edit the answer and add more explanation for your question.